# Why are the Elves at war with me and how can I make peace with them?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

- My fortress is at war with an Elven civilization.
- I don't know why it started, so I don't want this war.
- I have never attacked any other civilization, only killed/trapped invaders.
- I think that only Goblins should be my enemies. All of them, of course.

**How do I make peace with the Elves?**

I would love to give them some gifts in exchange for having less enemies.

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Comment: I can't say for sure it's still true, but it used to be that the elves would declare war if you cut down too many trees or tried to sell them products made from chopped-down trees.

Comment: "I would love to give them some gifts in exchange for having less enemies." Elves are not for sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a rookie at DF since I just started playing the other week.

This happened to me too: status war with the nearby elves when looking at the world map. They get offended if you cut trees or offer wooden items for trade (including items with wood as part of the production: soap, clear glass etc). More details [in the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Elf).

I did get a message from them saying that if I don't stop to cut down trees, I'll have to face the consequences. Then some time later a diplomat arrived and negotiated, agreeing on a 'quota' of how many trees I could cut down per year without consequences.

They haven't actually attacked me, but I've stayed clear of cutting down more trees than agreed. So if you go slow with the logging and save before making a trade with eleven merchants (it is hard not to offend them by offering the wrong goods), you should de-escalate the conflict.

Comment: I did not receive any quota so far. But they saw me cutting down trees and I offered to them some wrong items more than once. I even was attacked by wooden-armored elves once. And I'm not receiving any elven merchant anymore. They seem to be just butthurt and boycotting me like elves. I mean, they should formally declare a war to start a war!

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Maybe you accidentally harmed an elven trader. Like a dwarf throwing a tantrum and hurling some prepared giraffe intestines at an elf. At one point I had one dwarf throwing a heavy bin full of stuff at an innocent bystander and it killed them. Check the log of crimes to see if any elf was ever listed as the harmed party.

Comment: Where are you suggesting me to look at under `j`?

Comment: Justice -> Open/closed/cold cases

Comment: No open cases. No cold cases. All closed cases are "vandalism" or "disorderly conduct". Most commited by Dwarven Children. None of the cases mention the "injured party" as "elven trader".

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make peace with the Elves?

[According to the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=Diplomacy&oldid=276737), there are 2 ways of accomplishing that:

Attack them:

> Successfully obtaining tribute from a civilization at war with you may result in (presumably coerced) peace.

Just wait:

> Human and elven civilizations may also send diplomats to your fortress that will offer a peace agreement.